# How to access page that i navigate?

Tags: silverlight

I have page that i navigate to him

xaml:

```
<sdk:Frame x:Name="frameNavigator" Source="/Views/page0.xaml" JournalOwnership="OwnsJournal" Navigated="NavigatedPage_Event" />
```

The code:

frameNavigator.Navigate( new Uri( "/Views/Page1.xaml", UriKind.Relative ) );

I want to have ability to access to page1 from the main class that hold the page.

How can i do it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even if you're not using the MVVM pattern you could use MVVM-Lights messaging.

Register in your child view:

```
 Messenger.Default.Register<NotificationMessage>(this, "MyToken", DoSomething);
```

Send from your parent view:

```
 Messenger.Default.Send(new NotificationMessage(this, "SomeData"), "MyToken");
```

Example app:
https://bitbucket.org/dbeattie/navdemo

Comment: This does not answer the OP's question.

Comment: I took the question as how to communicate with sub pages in Silverlight, when using the NavigationService.